# Unable to set intervals of axis in a boxplot : RStudio

Tags: r

I am trying to make box plot from a large data set. The box plot doesn't look good due to having a huge interval. I want to fix the interval for y axis but it gives me error. I am adding my code and also the graph for your convenience

My code:

```
boxplot(POS$Profit.Amount~POS$BA.Node, xlab="Location",
        ylab = "Amount of Profit", main="Profit Per Location", col=colors, axis(2, seq(0,100,10)))
```

Graph:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFAAf.png

Comment: Use `ylim = c(0, 100)` to set the y axis limits instead of `axis(2, seq(0,100,10))`

Comment: @Dave2e But that way, I can change the range but I want to change the interval instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with a combination of ylim and yaxp options in the boxplot function:

```
#create some random data
y=runif(500, 20, 80)

#plot
boxplot(y, xlab="Location",
        ylab = "Amount of Profit", 
        main="Profit Per Location", yaxp= c(0,100, 10), ylim=c(0,100))
```

The above code will set the limits at 0 and 100 and yaxp will create 10 divisions between 0 and 100.